# Working with AJAX and Rails tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am fairly new to RoR and now I am at the point where i'm comfortable with rendering views using built-in RoR helpers. However, I would like to write the backend using Ruby and the front end using purely HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, AJAX. I was wondering if anyone could point me a tutorial on how to do the following:

- Load data with AJAX (I figured this out, but it'd be great if I could read even more tutorials on the subject)
- Update/edit data using AJAX
- How to format JSON data that I get back - such as putting the data into a table, etc.

I did quite a bit of searching myself, but I could not find a holistic tutorial... Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updating from database with ajax](http://www.techrecite.com/how-to-update-page-data-from-database-using-ajax/)

[Live editing with ajax](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html)

[Some helpful ajax snippits](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

These might be of some help.

The easy way is to use rails to do this. I would recommend it as its very easy.

[Here is](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm) a guide to setting that up.

[Heres a great](http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) link that can help as well.

The basics are you create a action in the controller

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Project added successfully'
        format.html { redirect_to projects_path }
        format.js { }
      else
        @created = false
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
      end
    end
  end
```

here you can see when the `create` action is triggered if it saves it adds the project and has
`format.html` for backup but tries to use `format.js`.

`format.js` renders `create.js.erb` which takes a mix of javascript and erb to update your page.

This is just a basic example and you can do even more with JSON.

`My create.js.erb`

```
<%if !defined? @created %>
  window.location.hash = ''
  $("#section-container").remove()
  $('#home h3 + a').after("#{j( render 'projects/project_boxes')}")
<% else %>
  $('.modal-dialog').css('max-height', '30em')
  $("#add-project").replaceWith("#{j(render 'projects/add_project')}")
<% end %>
```

my erb might be off.